# How can I get the original destination address of a packet after dnat?

Tags: netfilter

- I'm writing a packet filter module at userspace using `libnetfilter_queue`. But I don't know how to get the original destination address of a packet after it has gone through DNAT filter.
- When using socket, I can do it by using SO_ORIGINAL_DST but I don't know how when using `libnetfilter_queue`.

Thanks.